# Monotouch Ipad3 retina cannot run in full resolution

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, retina-display, ipad-3

What do I need to do to run in full resolution? No matter what I do,

```
UIScreen.MainContent.Bounds => {1024x768}
```

I am running Monodevelop 2.8.8.4 and I am setting my Deployment Target to 5.1

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't verify this since I don't have an iPad3, but on iPhone4's retina display bounds does not tell the whole story.

You need to take scale into consideration too;

```
CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGSize realSize = 
    CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width * scale, bounds.size.height * scale);
```

That would most likely translate to multiplying width and height by [`UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIScreen.Scale) on MonoTouch.

Comment: ok so scale is 2, but then why my images with native resolution do not fit on screen? Do i need to apply the scale manually to all my views?

Comment: @Luis If I remember correctly, you should be able to set the content mode to have it done automatically, `view.ContentMode=UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`. I usually just go with @2x resources, so it's been a while.

Comment: Do I need to do this to qll the views or to the top most view?